# When someone opens my website made in wordpress on a mobile device, to offer an Android app

Tags: android, wordpress

I have a website made in wordrpess, and now i've made a Android app. My question is how can i offer someone to install my android app if he/she opens my site with an android device ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this javascript:

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1; //&& ua.indexOf("mobile");
if(isAndroid) {
  // Do something!
}
```